# PostgreSQL Query trimming results unnecessarily

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm working on my first assignment using SQL on our class' PostgreSQL server.  A sample database has the (partial here) schema:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
  id int PRIMARY KEY,
  userStatus varchar(100),
  userType varchar(100),
  userName varchar(100),
  email varchar(100),
  age int,
  street varchar(100),
  city varchar(100),
  state varchar(100),
  zip varchar(100),
  CONSTRAINT users_status_fk FOREIGN KEY (userStatus) REFERENCES userStatus(name),
  CONSTRAINT users_types_fk FOREIGN KEY (userType)  REFERENCES userTypes(name)
);

CREATE TABLE events (
  id int primary key,
  title varchar(100),
  edate date,
  etime time,
  location varchar(100),
  user_id int,    -- creator of the event
  CONSTRAINT events_user_fk FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users(id)
);

CREATE TABLE polls (
  id int PRIMARY KEY,
  question varchar(100),
  creationDate date,
  user_id int,  --creator of the poll
  CONSTRAINT polls_user_fk FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users(id)
);
```

and a bunch of sample data (in particular, 127 sample users).

I have to write a query to find the number of polls created by a user within the past year, as well as the number of events created by a user that occurred in the past year.  The trick is, I should have rows with 0s for both columns if the user had no such polls/events.

I have a query which seems to return the correct data, but only for 116 of the 127 users, and I cannot understand why the query is trimming these 11 users, when the WHERE clause only checks attributes of the poll/event.  Following is my query:

```
SELECT u.id, u.userStatus, u.userType, u.email, -- Return user details
       COUNT(DISTINCT e.id) AS NumEvents, -- Count number of events
       COUNT(DISTINCT p.id) AS NumPolls -- Count number of polls
FROM (users AS u LEFT JOIN events AS e ON u.id = e.user_id) LEFT JOIN polls AS p ON u.id = p.user_id
WHERE (p.creationDate IS NULL OR ((now() - p.creationDate) < INTERVAL '1' YEAR) OR -- Only get polls created within last year
      e.edate IS NULL OR ((now() - e.edate) < INTERVAL '1' YEAR)) -- Only get events that happened during last year
GROUP BY u.id, u.userStatus, u.userType, u.email;
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: tested your schema with small amount of users - query works fine. Check up on data inserted for missed users.

Comment: What happens when you leave out the "COUNT" aggregate columns?  Do you get rows with nulls where you'd expect them to be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a different query seemed to work.  Here's what I ended up with:

```
SELECT u.id, u.userStatus, u.userType, u.email, COUNT(DISTINCT e.id) AS numevents, COUNT(DISTINCT p.id) AS numpolls
FROM users AS u LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT * FROM events WHERE ((now() - edate) < INTERVAL '1' YEAR)) AS e ON u.id = e.user_id
     LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT * FROM polls WHERE ((now() - creationDate) < INTERVAL '1' YEAR)) AS p ON u.id = p.user_id
GROUP BY u.id, u.userStatus, u.userType, u.email
;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to avoid using DISTINCT with sub-queries for example.

Comment: Removing the DISTINCT keyword from the COUNT aggregate did not change anything, it seems (except that the output was sorted by id, and now is unsorted).